Couple moves into a home and are attacked at night
A couple move into a new home. I think the house was brown and had a bit of wooded area to it and a swing set.  
The night time comes around and people with masks try to kill them. The couple tries fighting them and I think at the end one of them flees in a car.
Its not "The Purge".
I saw this a couple years ago probably around 2011. It was fairly new I believe; At the earliest made in the 2000s. It was made in the US in English. The cast was a man and a woman.

Welcome to Movies & TV! When did you see this? How old was it? What country was it set/made in? What language was it in? Can you describe any of the cast, name any of the actors? Please try to provide some more detail, otherwise I'm afraid this question is likely to be put on hold.

I saw this a couple years ago probably around 2011, It was fairly new I believe atleast made in the 2000s, it was made in the US with English Language, the cast was a man + a woman

Sounds quite similar to "The Strangers" 

"After returning from a wedding reception, a couple staying in an isolated vacation house receive a knock on the door in the mid-hours of the night. What ensues is a violent invasion by three strangers, their faces hidden behind masks. The couple find themselves in a violent struggle, in which they go beyond what either of them thought capable in order to survive."

The intruders wear masks, but they are the ones who flee in a car at the end. I also believe there was a swing-set in the backyard as well.
Check out the trailer below:




OMG THANK YOU SO MUCH
